# SOCKS error using Selenium with Python 2.7x and Tor

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, tor, socks

I currently have the below Python function. It is passed a URL and it accesses the URL through TOR before returning the HTML of the URL:

```
def connect_tor(url):
    LOCALHOST = "127.0.0.1"
    PORT = 9150
    useragent_list = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1944.0 Safari/537.36',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)',
                   'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.0) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14',
                   'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30']

    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, LOCALHOST, PORT)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.add_header('User-Agent', random.choice(useragent_list))
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    return response
```

This code works fine with no problem at all.

Later in the same .py file, I look to access a number of websites to enter data using Selenium and the Firefox browser. Nonetheless, a SOCKS5 error is always returned:-

```
Socks5Error: (1, 'general SOCKS server failure')
```

Researching this, it would appear that if the TOR connection is established initially within my script, then any future connections throughout the script would look to connect through this socket too. Therefore, with the above TOR connection established, how can I get Firefox to connect through Tor also. Here is my code below:

```
def selenium_function(album) #album is a URL
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        for password in password_list:
            driver.get(album)
            elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")
            elem.send_keys(password)
            elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    driver.quit()
```

Running the above script in a separate window (not containing Tor), it works fine and therefore I know there is no compatibility issue.